# How does my 'Free Fall Corps' fight?

Tags: military, strategy, fight

For whatever reason(I don't really care why), there is a portion of the military dedicated to combat while in a free-fall from varying heights. They are well trained at what they do and seem to always be there for epic fight scenes.

I only really need them for a few scenes, so they will mostly follow [The Rule of Cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool). Also, if you [land in a really cool position](http://colourwheelcomic.com/comic/page-103/), you can fall from however high up you want, as long as you didn't come from space or high flying aircraft. As for the ground, the free fall will continue until the fight scene is over so no time limit. There will commonly be debris falling with the Free Fall Corps and the people they are chasing after. The debris will conveniently disintegrate  into dust before hitting the ground to avoid damaging property and stuff.

As for maneuvering in the free fall, you just point your head where you want to go and you go that way. For speed, you have a speedy fast and regular speed. Speedy fast is when you just dive towards the ground, and you go faster than the falling debris. Regular speed is where you spread out your arms and legs so that your body is parallel to the ground and you fall at the same speed as the falling debris. You can slightly reduce the speed if you want, so you can get right under a falling rock if you like.

The Free Fall Corps troops will be wearing uniforms that look like snow trooper armor from The Empire Strikes Back, except the backpack is a small jetpack and light gray instead of white. It will be light armor and can protect from small hand held weapons, and the helmet is hardened to keep the wind out of their eyes. They are armed with military assault rifles and some explosive charges that can destroy the falling debris. They also have small rocket packs allowing them to go super-duper speed(about double of speedy fast) in short bursts if they choose to. The Free Fall Corps are trained for free fall skirmishes and know how to throw grenades to hit the target.

So this leads to the most important question, how do they fight? Obviously, it needs to look really cool and take into account the fact that there is a third dimension to travel through. Anywhere between 3-12 Free Fall soldiers can be in a fight against between 1-12 enemy combatants.

Yes I know that this is tossing several (if not all) rules of physics and a lot of common sense out the window so you can remove the 'this is impossible' part from your answer.

Comment: Aren't "free fall" and "maneuver" contradictory? If they can maneuver, they are not in free fall.

Comment: @AlexP, free fall sounds cooler than just falling. Can't forget The Rule Of Cool.

Comment: *Freifalljäger* sounds even cooler :)

Comment: If you have tricked your Freifalljäger out with grenades and rifles, havent you already decided how they will fight?  Because if they are going to rassle people in midair (my choice) why bring the guns?

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer - without knowing what the debris is, how it is violating the laws of physics (big rocks will fall faster than humans, regardless of the humans' profile), what range the engagements are occurring at and (most importantly) what the objectives of the combatants are (capture? kill? escape? look good on camera?) it comes down to guesses.

Comment: This is little different from interpersonal space combat (and as useless, I might add) with one exception: trajectories are ballistic.

Comment: They fight with magic to defeat the air-burst artillery filling the air with clouds of shrapnel as they descend, fired from well outside the range of their own handheld weapons. And as they land, that artillery follows them wherever they gather.

Comment: It sounds like you just want fighting style for zero-g situations. If you are in Space or Falling, it does not change anything.